# how to use quarkus and redis building a seckill microservice?

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x

how to use quarkus framework and redis ext building a seckill microservice? I search by google or bing,but no article for this topic. that logic like this code, but I can't to know write all use reactive api. Can help me?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SkillService {
    private static String ACT_ORDERS = "activity:goods:%s";
    private static String ACT_ORDER_ID = "activity:good-id";
    private static String ACT_USER_ORDER = "activity:user:%s";

    private static int LIMIT = 2;

    /**
     * SecKill TODO
     * <p>
     * first: judge user buy count and limit num, if buy num greater than limit num return
     * Exception<br/>
     * second: get one oderId return for the user<br/>
     * </p>
     */
    public Uni<String> snapUp(String userId) {
        int buyCount = valueCommands.keys(String.format(ACT_USER_ORDER, userId)).size();
        if(buyCount >= LIMIT){
            throw new Exception("is limit");
        }

        // queue pop 
        String orderId = listCommands.get(ACT_ORDER_ID).peek();
        if(orderId == null){
            throw new Exception("is sell out");
        }

        return Uni.createFrom().item(orderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mok, what exactly is valueCommands? It is neither found as an attribute/parameter or method variable.